# How to add signs next to a figure?

Tags: graphics, boxes

I want to decorate the side of a figure with signs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Smiley}
        \label{fig:smiley}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which we can compile as it is.

Comment: It is now compilable

Comment: Using a sample image, your code is compilable, otherwise it is not. Use instead `\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example-image}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

(red lines show text area border)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2mm and 8mm,
     N/.style = {draw, semithick, minimum size=7mm}
    ]
\node (n0) [inner sep=0pt] {\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example-image-duck}};
\node (n1) [N, below left = of n0.north west] {};
\node (n2) [N, left = of n0.west] {};
\node (n3) [N, above left = of n0.south west] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Duck. Quack, quack!}
\label{fig:duck}
    \end{figure}
See figure \ref{fig:duck}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Small nodes you can positioned relative to each other:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2mm and 8mm, % you can changedistances according to your wish
     N/.style = {draw, semithick, minimum size=7mm}
    ]
\node (n0) [inner sep=0pt] {\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example-image-duck}};
\node (n1) [N, left = of n0.west]   {};
\node (n2) [N, above = of n1]       {};
\node (n3) [N, below = of n1]       {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Duck. Quack, quack!}
\label{fig:duck}
    \end{figure}
See figure \ref{fig:duck} \dots
\end{document}
```

Vertical distance between them is defined by `node distance = <vertical distance> and <horizontal distance>`. You can change `<vertical distance>` (and `<horizontal distance>`)  according to your requirements.

[image]

Comment: Yes! This is really close. I'm just wondering about two more things. How can I put the nodes closer to eachother? So they are kind of centered vertically. And how can I put the image in the center, because the boxes are the with helpfull signs and not to be the focus.

Comment: @asasasasas, change `node distance` accordingly.  or change the way of their interposition. See addendum to answer,